# Unintended Recursivity - How do I stop or reset a function on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried making a jsFiddle for this, but it's not working right (I think because of the alerts I have set up to test my code), so hopefully someone can simply look at my JS and see the problem.

The issue is that when you close the div with the form (#verizoni516) and then re-open it, you get as many alerts as times you have closed the div and re-opened it, instead of the ONE alert I'm intending. Does that make any sense?

Here's the JS:

```
/*--------------Validation Functions-------------------*/
    function chkradio() {
        var elem = document.forms['vzi5'].elements['element_0'];
            len = elem.length - 1;
            chkvalue = '';
            sevenPlus = false;
            fourToSix = false;
            threeMin = false;
        for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
            if(elem[i].checked) chkvalue = elem[i].value;   
        }
        if (chkvalue == '') {
            $('#radio-error').fadeIn('fast').effect("bounce", {times:3}, 'fast', function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#radio-error').fadeOut('slow');}, 2000);
            });
        }
        if (chkvalue >= 7) {
            sevenPlus = true;
        } else if (chkvalue >= 4 && chkvalue <= 6) {
            fourToSix = true;
        } else {
            threeMin = true;
        }
    };
    function chkselect() {
        var elem = document.forms['vzi5'].elements['element_1'];
            len = elem.length - 1;
            chkvalue = '';
            likeNew = false;
            minProb = false;
            nonFunc = false;
        for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
            if (elem[i].selected) chkvalue = elem[i].value;
        }
        if (chkvalue == '') {
            elem.focus();
            $('#select-error').fadeIn('fast').effect("bounce", {times:3}, 'fast', function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#select-error').fadeOut('slow');}, 2000);
            });
        } else if (chkvalue === 'Like New - No Functional Problems') {
            likeNew = true;
        } else if (chkvalue === 'Minor Functional Problems') {
            minProb = true;
        } else {
            nonFunc = true;
        }
    };
    function chkbox() {
        var elem = document.forms['vzi5'].elements['element_2[]'];
            chkvalue = elem.checked;
            iUnderstand = true;
        if (chkvalue === true) {
            iUnderstand;
        } else {
            iUnderstand = false;
            elem.focus();
            $('#check-error').fadeIn('fast').effect("bounce", {times:3}, 'fast', function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#check-error').fadeOut('slow');}, 2000);
        });
        }
    };
//Calling the validation functions---------------------------
$('#verizon img.apple, #unlocked img.apple').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').fadeOut(500).animate({"top": "-414px"}, 100).fadeIn('fast', function(){
    });
        $('#verizon516').animate({"top": "+=557px"}, 500, function(){
            $(this).animate({"top": "-=20px"}, 200);
        });
    $('div.next').click(function(){
        chkradio();
        chkselect();
        chkbox();
        if (sevenPlus === true) {
            if (likeNew === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 7+ and functions like new.');
            } else if (minProb === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 7+ and has minor functional problems');
            } else if (nonFunc === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 7+ and device does NOT function.');
            } else {

            };
        };
        if (fourToSix === true) {
            if (likeNew === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 4-6 and functions like new.');
            } else if (minProb === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 4-6 and has minor functional problems');
            } else if (nonFunc === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 4-6 and device does NOT function.');
            } else {

            };
        };
        if (threeMin === true) {
            if (likeNew === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 1-3 and functions like new.');
            } else if (minProb === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 1-3 and has minor functional problems');
            } else if (nonFunc === true && iUnderstand === true) {
                alert('Condition is 1-3 and device does NOT function.');
            } else {

            };
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: By the way, I had "return;" in each of those currently empty else statements, and having that or not having it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `div.next` click handler out of the other click handler, it will cause a new handler to get registered every time you click on one of the `#verizon img.apple, #unlocked img.apple` elements which intern gets called one after another.

```
/*--------------Validation Functions-------------------*/

function chkradio() {
    var elem = document.forms['vzi5'].elements['element_0'];
    len = elem.length - 1;
    chkvalue = '';
    sevenPlus = false;
    fourToSix = false;
    threeMin = false;
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        if (elem[i].checked) chkvalue = elem[i].value;
    }
    if (chkvalue == '') {
        $('#radio-error').fadeIn('fast').effect("bounce", {
            times: 3
        }, 'fast', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#radio-error').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
    if (chkvalue >= 7) {
        sevenPlus = true;
    } else if (chkvalue >= 4 && chkvalue <= 6) {
        fourToSix = true;
    } else {
        threeMin = true;
    }
};

function chkselect() {
    var elem = document.forms['vzi5'].elements['element_1'];
    len = elem.length - 1;
    chkvalue = '';
    likeNew = false;
    minProb = false;
    nonFunc = false;
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        if (elem[i].selected) chkvalue = elem[i].value;
    }
    if (chkvalue == '') {
        elem.focus();
        $('#select-error').fadeIn('fast').effect("bounce", {
            times: 3
        }, 'fast', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#select-error').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 2000);
        });
    } else if (chkvalue === 'Like New - No Functional Problems') {
        likeNew = true;
    } else if (chkvalue === 'Minor Functional Problems') {
        minProb = true;
    } else {
        nonFunc = true;
    }
};

function chkbox() {
    var elem = document.forms['vzi5'].elements['element_2[]'];
    chkvalue = elem.checked;
    iUnderstand = true;
    if (chkvalue === true) {
        iUnderstand;
    } else {
        iUnderstand = false;
        elem.focus();
        $('#check-error').fadeIn('fast').effect("bounce", {
            times: 3
        }, 'fast', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#check-error').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
};
//Calling the validation functions---------------------------
$('#verizon img.apple, #unlocked img.apple').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').fadeOut(500).animate({
        "top": "-414px"
    }, 100).fadeIn('fast', function () {});
    $('#verizon516').animate({
        "top": "+=557px"
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "top": "-=20px"
        }, 200);
    });
});
//move this out of the other click handler
$('div.next').click(function () {
    chkradio();
    chkselect();
    chkbox();
    if (sevenPlus === true) {
        if (likeNew === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 7+ and functions like new.');
        } else if (minProb === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 7+ and has minor functional problems');
        } else if (nonFunc === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 7+ and device does NOT function.');
        } else {

        };
    };
    if (fourToSix === true) {
        if (likeNew === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 4-6 and functions like new.');
        } else if (minProb === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 4-6 and has minor functional problems');
        } else if (nonFunc === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 4-6 and device does NOT function.');
        } else {

        };
    };
    if (threeMin === true) {
        if (likeNew === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 1-3 and functions like new.');
        } else if (minProb === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 1-3 and has minor functional problems');
        } else if (nonFunc === true && iUnderstand === true) {
            alert('Condition is 1-3 and device does NOT function.');
        } else {

        };
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bNtzb/)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I probably should have seen that despite the fact that I'm a newbie. Additionally, I was wondering what, if anything, I should do about those empty else statements? I've never seen it in anyone else's code . . .

Comment: much obliged. It looked wrong to me to end that statement with an } else if {, but it certainly works. Thanks!

Comment: @user3127799 read the docs.. you can find details info in the mdn blogs about most of these things like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are binding the click event for `div.next` inside the click event for `#verizon img.apple, #unlocked img.apple`, so every time the outer event is clicked, you are re-binding the inner click event. Fix this by moving the event binding for `div.next` outside the click event for `#verizon img.apple, #unlocked img.apple`

```
$('#verizon img.apple, #unlocked img.apple').click(function(){
    // .. contents here
});
$('div.next').click(function(){
    // ... contents here
});
```

Comment: Thank you!I'm so glad it was something easy :)

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event to $('div.next') every time $('#verizon img.apple, #unlocked img.apple') is clicked. Which means it will fire once for each time it is bound. Move the code for $('div.next') out of the $('#verizon img.apple, #unlocked img.apple') click handler.